# How to connect a payment device using serial port commutator?(Payment device: Spire Payments SPc5)

Tags: c#, payment, pos

My client has requirement to integrate the POS application with a payment device for payment.
One third party company has given the spire payment spc5 device. This company did not provide any dll to connect the device and send request and also get response. They have given document and told us to create a dll to send request and get response. As the device is connected to the system with serial port. If we need to communicate with this device using C# code then we will use ASCII format values.

Kindly help me to communicate with the device and how to send request and capture the response.

Comment: StackOverflow is not here to do your job for you. We can only answer clearly defined questions. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can connect to the device Via Rs232 or Ethernet connection. PCPOS service or something equivalent must be implemented in your device( SPIRE pos) and you must use it's protocol to transceiving data.